# How to dynamically change the text in an AlertDialog while it is showing?

Tags: android, text, timer, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog that is displayed, and want the text to have a countdown. While trying to implement it in the following way, the dialog displays exactly as needed, but I am trying to figure out how to make one of the TextViews change to the timer while the dialog is displayed. When I try to implement it in this way, it crashes, as you can see in the log info.

```
public void startOverlay()
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View boxLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);

        builder.setView(boxLayout);

        Typeface flatui = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Flat-UI-Font.ttf");
        TextView t1 = (TextView)boxLayout.findViewById(R.id.dialogtext1);
        final TextView t2 = (TextView)boxLayout.findViewById(R.id.dialogtext2);
        t1.setTypeface(flatui);
        t2.setTypeface(flatui);

        final AlertDialog receivedBox = builder.create();
        receivedBox.show();

        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                final int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                log("Tick: " + seconds);
                if (seconds == 0)
                    receivedBox.dismiss();

                Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {

                         // executed on the UI thread
                        t2.setText(seconds);
                     }
                });

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                receivedBox.dismiss();
                log("done!");
                beginFirst();
            }
         }.start();

    }
```

Log info:

```
06-24 12:01:18.977: E/AndroidRuntime(11682): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 12:01:18.977: E/AndroidRuntime(11682): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5
06-24 12:01:18.977: E/AndroidRuntime(11682):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:242)
06-24 12:01:18.977: E/AndroidRuntime(11682):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3773)
06-24 12:01:18.977: E/AndroidRuntime(11682):    at com.workout.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:163)
06-24 12:01:18.977: E/AndroidRuntime(11682):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-24 12:01:18.977: E/AndroidRuntime(11682):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 12:01:18.977: E/AndroidRuntime(11682):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-24 12:01:18.977: E/AndroidRuntime(11682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
06-24 12:01:18.977: E/AndroidRuntime(11682):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 12:01:18.977: E/AndroidRuntime(11682):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-24 12:01:18.977: E/AndroidRuntime(11682):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
06-24 12:01:18.977: E/AndroidRuntime(11682):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
06-24 12:01:18.977: E/AndroidRuntime(11682):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "as I cannot change the text"? Compile error? App crash? App hang? Development OS crash?

Answer (score 1):

You can not change or modify your views outside UI thread. Try following code to update your TextView. Put this code in `onTick`.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         // executed on the UI thread
         your_text_view.setText("your string");
     }
});
```

Comment: I tried this code in onTick(), making my TextView t2 final so as it was saying 'cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class' but now when the line 't2.setText(seconds);' inside run() executes it gives me a 'ResourcesNotFoundException' error on t2.setText(), am I doing this wrong?

Comment: are you setting any "string" resource inside run() method? Error generally comes due to any resource you have declared in your resource file "values", can't not find by project. Just do one thing, Click Project-> clean . After cleaning your project, rebuild it. Sometimes "R.java" file refer to old values which are not in project.

Comment: The new log info and code has been updated in the original question, thanks!

Comment: @AndroidNewbie - TextView takes a `resource id` as in `R.string.mystring` which is a `int` or a 'String', cast your `seconds` to a `String` and this should be fixed.

Something like  `t2.setText(String.valueOf(seconds));`